# Stop search dialog from coming up in MS Access form

Tags: forms, ms-access

The "Find and Replace" dialog keeps coming up after my button event runs. Why and what can I do to stop it?

[image]

```
Private Sub btn_Find_Click()
    Dim query_string As String

    'MsgBox (Me.InventoryDetailsID)

    query_string = "SELECT " & _
               "tbl_Inventory_Header.InventoryHeaderID, " & _
               "tbl_Inventory_Header.InventoryTitle, " & _
               "tbl_Inventory_Header.Author, " & _
               "tbl_Lookup_MediaTypes.MediaTypeDescription, " & _
               "tbl_Inventory_Details.ShelfNumber, " & _
               "tbl_Lookup_Vendors.VendorName, " & _
               "tbl_Inventory_Header.Year_Publish_Produced, " & _
               "tbl_Inventory_Header.InventoryDescription " & _
               "FROM (((tbl_Inventory_Header " & _
               "INNER JOIN tbl_Inventory_Details ON tbl_Inventory_Details.InventoryHeaderID = tbl_Inventory_Header.InventoryHeaderID) " & _
               "INNER JOIN tbl_Lookup_Vendors ON tbl_Lookup_Vendors.VendorID = tbl_Inventory_Header.VendorID) " & _
               "INNER JOIN tbl_Lookup_MediaTypes ON tbl_Lookup_MediaTypes.MediaTypeID = tbl_Inventory_Header.MediaTypeID) " & _
               "WHERE tbl_Inventory_Details.InventoryDetailsID LIKE '" & Me.InventoryDetailsID & "';"

    Me.Controls!test.Value = query_string

    'MsgBox ("Querying for record data")
    CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qry_Inventory_Header_ISBN").SQL = query_string

    Dim recordSet As DAO.recordSet
    Set recordSet = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("qry_Inventory_Header_ISBN")

    If Not recordSet.RecordCount > 0 Then
        MsgBox ("No record found for barcode " & Me.Controls!InventoryDetailsID)
        GoTo Exit_btn_SearchByHeaderId_Click
    Else
        'MsgBox ("record found")
    End If

    'MsgBox (recordSet!InventoryTitle)

    'MsgBox ("filling controls")
    Me.Controls!InventoryTitle.Value = recordSet!InventoryTitle
    Me.Controls!Author = recordSet!Author
    Me.Controls!MediaTypeDescription = recordSet!MediaTypeDescription
    Me.Controls!VendorName = recordSet!VendorName
    Me.Controls!Year_Publish_Produced = recordSet!Year_Publish_Produced
    Me.Controls!InventoryDescription = recordSet!InventoryDescription
    Me.Controls!ShelfNumber = recordSet!ShelfNumber

    Me.Controls!ISBN.SetFocus

    On Error GoTo Err_btn_SearchByHeaderId_Click
        'MsgBox ("got error")
        Screen.PreviousControl.SetFocus
        DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdFind

Exit_btn_SearchByHeaderId_Click:
        'MsgBox ("exit")
        Exit Sub

Err_btn_SearchByHeaderId_Click:
        MsgBox Err.Description
        Resume Exit_btn_SearchByHeaderId_Click
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Find dialog derives at this command `DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdFind` towards the bottom just before the error handlers.

And according to the code, this Find command will always run since no `If Then`, `Do While Loop`, `For Next`, or `Goto` is wrapped around it.

Consider removing it, re-positioning it, or placing an `Exit Sub` before it if this Find command should be part of an error handle.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even realize that was there. It snuck in because in a previous iteration I was actually using a "find" button, but as the code shows, I changed the name. From the beginning, I wanted a custom search, but I'm a little new, and the original choice of a find button was a mistake.